# Dojo - finding out which button was clicked on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, dojo

If I connect to my form's onSubmit event, how can I find out which button on the form was used for submit? Or, if the form was submitted by pressing the Enter key on an element, how can I find out which element was in focus?

I cannot rely on ExplicitOriginalTarget property of the event object, as this is Mozilla-specific.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use submit buttons, you can easily run a script when a button is pressed, in that script you may submit the form (simply call the forms `.submit()` method), that way you will easily know what button was pressed, and any submit not originating from your code must then of course originate from the user pressing enter.